# Is there a way to manually add the file format of a file parameter in Swagger?

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

I am using Swagger for endpoint documentation for a Spring Boot project. One of the endpoints parameters are a String "digApp" and a csv file "file". However, when sending a request using Swagger the file type is not set to csv. Although, using postman for instance works perfectly.

The curl from Swagger:

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:8093/scorecardrule?digApp=a" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@DigAppSmartSheet_template.csv;type="`

I tried the above curl command from terminal but setting `type=text/csv` and it also it worked perfectly.

The method signature:

```
    @PostMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "Upload new csv", response = Integer.class)
    public void saveCSV(
        @ApiParam(value = "The DigApp name required to upload scoreCardRule", required = true) @RequestPart("digApp") String digApp,
        @ApiParam(value = "The SmartSheet CSV File is required", required = true, type="file") @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
```

My question is, is there a way to set the `type=` to a value?

Comment: Can you post your generated swagger.json?

Comment: By "sending a request using Swagger" do you mean Swagger UI? If yes, which [version of Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) do you use - 2.x or 3.x?